# How to access information stored in the Root.plist Settings Bundle (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I did some searching yesterday, but I couldn't really find anything that satisfactorily answered my question. I was helping a friend of mine, and he had part of his information stored for the app in the Settings.app, with a Root.plist file in the settings bundle holding the information. I had no prior experience to working with this, so I was unsure how to get this information. I tried `let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathforResource("Root", ofType: "plist")` but this just returned `nil`. So what would be the proper way to access this information?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Xcode 13.4.1 and Swift 5. Here are the codes to get Root.plist in the main bundle:

```
let settingsBundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Settings", ofType: "bundle")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: settingsBundle!)
let rootPlist = url.appendingPathComponent("Root.plist").path
let dic = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: rootPlist)
print(dic ?? "")
```

The first step is to get the path to the main bundle's "Settings.bundle". Next, build a URL for this path. The final step is to add "Root.plist" to the url. My print can get the content of my Root.plist content.

Here is another usage based on this finding. In my project, there are some user default settings defined in the Settings.bundle. Those user default setting names can be localized. The localization string files are within this Settings.bundle, not like the case of localized strings in the project or the main bundle path. Here is a case of getting the localized user default setting name: "Allow bulk delete".

```
let settingsBundle = Bundle.main.path(
  forResource: "Settings",
  ofType: "bundle")
let bdl = Bundle(path: settingsBundle!)
let s = NSLocalizedString(
  "rkAllowBulkDelete", 
  tableName: "Root",
  bundle: bdl!, 
  comment: "Localized name for setting \"Allow bulk delete\"")
  print(s)
```

And this is the definition of rkAllowBulkDelete in en.lproj\Root.string file:

```
...
"rkAllowBulkDelete" = "Allow bulk deletion";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to access the standard user defaults, which could be done like this:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let example = userDefaults.boolForKey("mykey")
```

Check out [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) documentation for more details.

EDIT:
You can get the keys in the standard user defaults like this:

```
for key in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys {
    println(key.description)
}
```

However this might give you more keys than what you have inside the Root.plist. Also you might want to edit your question and mention that you want to get a list of keys from the Root.plist, since nothing like this is mentioned there.

Comment: I know how to use UserDefaults but I don't know what the keys are in the root file so I don't know how to access them.